# JavaFX embeded browser memory leak

Tags: memory, javafx, webview, memory-leaks

I am using [embedded browser in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html). On my webpage, using Javascript, I dynamically create lots of checkboxes + some other components and remove them from the DOM afterwards. What is strange, after performing every "create/remove" cycle the memory usage is growing. Maybe it could be related to the click events attached to my elements? It seems like a memory leak, I have no idea how could I fix this. In regular browser like Chrome everything works fine.

Comment: Please take a look at this stackoverflow [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668910/how-to-clear-javafx-webview-memory-usage-after-closing-stage)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with finding memory leaks but I've been meaning to use [Plumbr](http://plumbr.eu) to test my JavaFX app for those - maybe you can use that?

You might have to sit there and keep clicking on stuff or script lots of interaction for Plumbr to notice the leak, since it seems to be focused on JSP apps which have a lot of simultaneous users.